# How to add an icon after text widget in an expanded widget?

Tags: flutter, layout

[image]

I want the arrow_right icon close after the Text Widget, but I have to wrap the text with a Expanded as it might overflow

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally， Flexible can do it!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this can solve it.

```
Row(
  children: const [
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        'this line is overflow, but icon is in right position',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
        softWrap: false,
        maxLines: 2,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // new
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

or

```
Row(
  children: const [
    Expanded(
      child: FittedBox(
        child: Text(
          'this line is overflow, but icon is in right position',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
          softWrap: false,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

code Example

```
return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Expanded(
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[

                  const Text(
                    'Line 1',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  ),

                  Row(
                    children: const [
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'this line might overflow',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                    ],
                  ),

                  Row(
                    children: const [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          'this line is overflow, but icon is in right position // this line is overflow, but icon is in right position',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                          softWrap: false,
                          //maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // new
                        ),
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                    ],
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
```

***result Image***
[image]

I'll tell you two ways I know of.

1. Use `Container` Widget

- How to fix the size by giving `width:`  This method allows you to attach an icon next to the text.

2. Use `Expanded` Widget

- 'Expanded' is a percentage. Since you are using one `Expanded` widget now, the `Text` widget is taking up all the remaining space except for the space for the `Icon` widget.

You can use it according to the conditions of your app.

Comment: it doesn't work，

Comment: May I know what was the result?

Comment: @chdo I've attached a code example and an image in the answer.

Comment: I need no space between Text and icon，

Comment: i add a new image to the question，that might explain my expect

Comment: Can your text always be 2 or 3 lines? Or is the second text always one line?

Comment: my text should always be 1 line

Comment: @chdo Edited the answer. I've fixed two ways to work around it when I think of it. I hope you can solve the problem.

Comment: It seems that I can't meet this requirement in a simple way except for custom widget，   thanks anyway @Jungwon

Answer (score 0):

You should try this solution

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 130,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 5,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const Expanded(
                                flex: 2,
                                child: FittedBox(
                                  child: Text("line 1"),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 3,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: Row(
                                      children: const [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "this line might overflow",
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        AspectRatio(
                                          aspectRatio: 1,
                                          child: FittedBox(
                                              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right)),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                    Expanded(
                                        child: Row(
                                      children: const [
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "this line is overflow, the icon is in right position",
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        AspectRatio(
                                          aspectRatio: 1,
                                          child: FittedBox(
                                              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right)),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Solution Image**
[image]

N.B: This Solution is totally responsive.

Answer (score -1):

******* TRY THIS  ********

```
Text("Any Text Add",
                      textScaleFactor: 0.85,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12
                        ),
                      )
```